# IE css issue on first page load, works OK on page refresh

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am stumped as to why, a site I am working on, works perfectly on all browsers, but fails to load CSS on first time page loads with IE. Once I hit refresh, it loads OK.

Here's how it loads first time:
[image]

Here's how it loads after refreshing (this is the correct load):
[image]

The site [address is here](http://networkfx.com.au). I have not found any answers on this so, Any pointers/links would be wonderful

Comment: Try changing @import parabola style.css to a direct load of the file with a link.

Comment: Hi @vogomatix thank you for the suggestion. I am afraid I do not understand what you are suggesting though? When I look at the code for the page loaded, the styles.css is loaded via a direct link already. I must be misunderstanding your suggestion. Can you elaborate please. Thanks!

Comment: It worked first time using 11 / windows 8.1 -  what versions of IE does it not work in?

Comment: Hi @Code uniquely, I am using Win 8.0 and IE10.0.9200.16721. Thanks

Comment: I am with Code Uniquely I can't get it not to work correctly. Open the F12 tools and check how the styles are applied to those elements. Check your network waterfall to see if something is not loaded, I saw no 404s, but a lot of aborted requests. Also you should be upgraded to Win 8.1 & IE 11 by now. That is a free, automatic upgrade, just a side note.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the feedback. I sorted the issue by moving up the list of CSS links the CSS file containing the responsive elements. Unfortunately on the upgrade I am stuck with Win 8 Enterprise, so I cannot get it.